# Eclipse Luna With MinGW: "Launch failed. Binary not found."

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows

I have searched all over the web and have tried everything I could to fix this problem, to no avail.  So here I am making a new post, hoping to fix this terribly frustrating problem.

---

I have the Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers that on my Windows 7 computer.  The version of Eclipse is Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) and the build ID is 20150219-0600.

I have MinGW installed onto my computer, and I downloaded all the package choices just to be safe.

---

I create a C++ project.  The "Project type" is **Executable > Empty Project** and the "Toolchains" is "Cross GCC".

I select both "Debug" and "Release" in the "Configurations".

*I leave the "Cross compiler prefix" blank because I don't know what to write.*  I then put in "F:\MinGW" as the "Cross compiler path".

I create a new source file in the project and write the infamous Hello World program (in C++, of course).  When I save the project, it gives me two errors in the "Problems" tab:

```
Program "g++" not found in PATH
Program "gcc" not found in PATH
```

When I build the project, it adds on another error:

```
Program "make" not found in PATH
```

I go to **Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Tool Chain Editor** and change the "Current builder" from "Gnu Make Builder" to "CDT Internal Builder".

The error `Program "make" not found in PATH` then disappears.

I go to **Window > Preferences > C/C++ > New C/C++ Project Wizard > Makefile Project** and set the "Binary parser" to "PE Windows Parser".  I clear the project, save the project, and build the project, but the 2 errors remain.

If I go to **Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Environment** and set the value of the "PATH" variable to "F:\MinGW\bin", still nothing happens and the two errors remain.

Now, when I attempt to run the project (ctrl + F11), it spits out the error `Launch Failed. Binary not found.`

In the "Project Explorer", I see a HelloWorld file that contains an "Includes" file (containing the compiler libraries?), a "Debug" folder (containing a HelloWorld.exe and a main.o), and a main.cpp file (containing my Hello World program).

---

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read this and for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update environment variable `PATH`. Check [this](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/howto_install_the_mingw_gcc_compiler_suite) page.

> You must add C:\MinGW\bin; to your user PATH environment variable manually.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, not a solution, at least you want to make sure the following.

1. Recheck that the PATH is set up right. Sometime we think we did, but the computer does not. In the command line, type the following command to see the gcc installed right and PATH is set right.

   - gcc --version
   - echo $PATH
     or
   - echo %PATH%
2. All things are right as you did above, but it does not work?, Then remove and reinstall mingw and eclipse CDT cleanly. Don't change and keep the default options in the Eclipse CDT. Without any option changes CDT, it should work NOWADAYS. Eclipse CDT(8.7, 8.8) is pretty much stable.

Blessings,

(a debtor)<><